# Passenger always reads production settings from database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I have deployed my rails 3 app using nginx and passenger on my test server where RAILS_ENV is set to test. I have also added `rails_env test;` to the server block in my nginx.conf.
But still passeneger is reading the production settings from my database.yml. How can i fix this ?

Thank You

Comment: How are you starting the Rails app?  Are you declaring the environment when you start it?

Comment: can you post relevant nginx.conf info? it works for develop env?